# having part of system in cloud and some in local data center

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, cloud

I have a general question regarding hosting an application in the cloud such as such as AWS, or Azure.
Does it make senses to have my application servers, BDs in the cloud while having the Web servers in our local non-cloud data center? The reason I am asking is because of some special requirements is easier to have our Web servers in our in-house datacenter rather having it in the cloud. 
so I am looking for any issues like slowness and etc with this approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are suggesting really makes no sense.

There are hybrid architectures, but for most of these implementations you have the web / application servers in the cloud, and are accessing a database still in your non-cloud data center.

Most cloud providers do web serving really, really well: load balancing, autoscaling, monitoring, and content distribution networks all tied together with automation mean that it is highly doubtful that you can do it better in-house.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and agree. However, I didn't want to get into more details. Our web server is very customized with many built-in in-house modules and etc and does a lot of various authentications before sending the request to the application server. So not very easy to move that part to cloud. So if request hit our load balancer and the load balancer send the request to our in-house web server and then the web server sends the request to the application servers in the cloud, will that be too much latency? Do customers notice slowness?

Comment: Yes, customers notice latency.  You can reduce this by using Direct Connect and connecting to a region close to your data center, but you could still be looking at 100x more latency than all in house.

Comment: @borna *"will that be too much latency? Do customers notice slowness?"*  There is only one way to find out... try it.  Actually, there's a second way that's easier... configure a proxy server (e.g. HAProxy) in the cloud and loop your requests our of your DC to the proxy and then back.  This simulates how your system performs under the proposed configuration, but doubles the amount of latency since the request goes out and back, and you should find it *very* informative.  I split an application this way once and found that each page view required 13 round trips, minimum, most of them pointless.